# Custom AlertDialog changes/overrides statusbar color, so how can I fix that?

Tags: java, android

So I'm using this library: https://github.com/Codigami/CFAlertDialog in my app and have this very annoying issue that I can't seem to find a solution for.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, just like the screenshots from OP's README, I'm getting the light gray color on my statusbar. I opened an issue but I doubt if I will get any support, considering the fact that OP hasn't updated the library in a while or answered other open issues which brings me here.

My app uses AMOLED dark theme overall and this seems to annoy.

Also, feel free to let me know if there's an alternative library similar to this. I use this one for the full-width button integration, and custom dialog UI.

Thank you.

Comment: You could probably just fork the library and, as the status bar colour is ordinarily set from the `colorPrimaryDark` attribute, change that value in the parent Style to whatever fits the theme of your app.

Comment: @PPartisan Thank you for your time and answer, will try it now and see if it works.

Comment: @PPartisan that library doesn't seem to have any app theme or colors added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a library error. Until the developer fixes it, you can override the dialog theme to avoid the statusbar color change. Add this to your project's styles.xml file

```
<style name="CFDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CFDialog.Animation</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.0</item>

    <!-- This line does the magic -->
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
</style>
```

[image]